# List functions in the order they are executed

Tags: c, gprof

I define several functions in a file (the main function is defined by someone else).

I can use gprof to analyze how many times my functions have been called, but is there a way of getting a list with the functions by the order they are called in the main program?

of course I could write a message in the beginning of each function but there are quite a few of them.

I would also be happy if it could be done by gdb by specifying something like "break in the first function that is called in this file".
Again they are too many to list explicitly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you don't want to use trace or truss or similar?

Comment: I am open to suggestions, I don't actually know these tools, I will check them out.

Comment: There are various names and features and are a utility per OS. Truss was the Solaris tool, trace provided similar fuctionality for AIX. These names are pretty common, but your particular OS may have another name AND with that a somewhat different set of features. Good luck.

Comment: None of these tools exist in the linux readhat computer I have access to. does anyone know what would be the tool to use in this system?